# creating class instances using an image in java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, png, rgb

I've been following this tutorial on youtube for creating a game in java and at one point in the tutorial you're supposed to load a 64x64 PNG image and read the RGB values for each pixel and create classes accordingly. I get no errors but, all I get is a blank screen.  The program is supposed to create an instance of the Player class when a pixel is blue and a block class when a pixel is red.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;

    private BufferedImage level = null;


    public Game(){
        new Window(1000, 563, "Wizard Game", this);
        start();

        handler = new Handler();

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));

        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();

        level = loader.LoadImage("wizard_level.png");   
        loadLevel(level);
    }

    private void start(){
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void stop(){
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 60;
        while(isRunning){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta --;
            }
            if(isRunning)
                render();
            frames ++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop(); 

    }

    public void tick(){
        handler.tick();
    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 563);

        handler.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

        }

    //loading level
    private void loadLevel(BufferedImage image){
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        for(int xx = 0; xx > w; xx++){
            for(int yy = 0; yy < h; yy++){              
                int pixel = image.getRGB(xx, yy);   
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int blue = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                int green = (pixel) & 0xff;

                if(red == 255)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, ID.Block));

                if(blue == 255)
                    handler.addObject(new Wizard(xx*32, yy*32, ID.Player, handler));

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Game();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line `level = loader.LoadImage("wizard_level.png");` it's suppose to be `level = loader.LoadImage("/wizard_level.png");` you forgot the `/` at the beginning of the path or else the compiler will just read it as a string